# Dropdown list value repeated

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

i have 4 objects in my database eg zen ,maruthi and scorpio ..after binding the values to dropdown list i can only see scorpio repeated 3 times ..

instead of getting it as

```
zen
maruthi
scorpio
```

..i get scorpio

```
scorpio 
scorpio..
```

Code

```
List<Cab> CabTypeList = new List<Cab>();
using (DataTable table = SqlDBConnector.ExecuteSelectCommand("GetCabType", CommandType.StoredProcedure))
{
    //check if any record exist or not
    if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        //Lets go ahead and create the list of cab

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            cab.CabType =  row["CabType"].ToString();
            cab.CabId = Convert.ToInt32(row["Cab_Id"]);
            CabTypeList.Add(cab);
        }
    }
}
```

ASPX page

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    CabDbAccess cabdbaccess = new CabDbAccess();
    DropDownList1.DataSource = cabdbaccess.GetCabType();
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "CabType"; // the items to be displayed in the list items
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "CabId"; // the id of the items displayed
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Can you also post GetCabType procedure ... that will give the complete picture .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is `cab` coming from ? Make sure you are adding a new item in the `foreach` loop.

```
public List<Cab> GetCabType()
{  
   List<Cab> CabTypeList = new List<Cab>();
   // to do : get your data in the data table. 
   foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
   {
     var cab= new Cab();
     cab.CabType =  row["CabType"].ToString();
     cab.CabId = Convert.ToInt32(row["Cab_Id"]);
     CabTypeList.Add(cab);
   }
   return CabTypeList;
}
```

Comment: the data is coming from database..am getting different data from database but its getting replaced by new value.Like if 1st value from cab is zen then 2nd is maruthi ,the list values are getting over written and it becomes maruthi maruthi.

Comment: hey it worked !! thanks a lot!! after clearing the project :) thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever `cab` is, you're adding it three times. You end up having three items in your list that are all the same object. You probably want to add something like  `Cab cab = new Cab();` at the top of the loop. Then you'll add a distinct one each time.